# Chrome is ignoring my saved passwords on OSX after keychain deletion

Tags: macos, google-chrome, passwords, keychain

I'm using Google Chrome on 3 OS X machines. For one of these machines, the **username and password autocomplete** is not working at all, even though I am asked to store the password after every login. I'm not sure but i suspect that this has to do with the fact that I had do delete the keychain after upgrading to el capitan.

I can confirm, that in the "Password and Forms" settings,

- `enable autofill ...`
- `offer to save ...`

are selected.

However, if I click on `Manage Passwords` in Chrome, both lists stay empty, even if I accept to store new entered passwords. When I navigate to "password.google.com" all of my saved passwords are listed.

I already tried removing Chrome using AppCleaner and also hit the reset settings button. But it's still not saving the passwords.

Any ideas?